# Partitioning a graph in cycles of four

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, set-partition, cyclic-decomposition

I have the following question:

> Suppose that in a simple undirected graph with $4n$ vertices, each vertex has degree at least $2n$.
>
> Is it true that we can always partition the set of vertices in $n$ parts of size $4$ such that the vertices of every part can form a cycle (of length $4$)?

I was able to prove only that it is possible to find $4$ vertices that form a cycle.

Comment: This was a conjecture of Erdős and Faudree resolved in [this 2010 paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00373-010-0948-3).

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Excelent!

Comment: Wow! A proof over 40 pages. No wonder I couldn't solve it in one day!